# Proguard Configuration Issue

Tags: java, proguard, java-web-start

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.appstruts.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>StrutsMavenPOC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>StrutsMavenPOC</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
  <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0.3</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>             
            <configuration>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <includeDependency>true</includeDependency>
                <options>
                    <option>-target 1.8</option>                    
                    <option>-ignorewarnings</option>                    
                    <option>-dontoptimize</option>
                    <option>-keepdirectories</option>
                    <option>-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile</option>
                    <option>-keepparameternames</option>
                    <option>-keep public class com.appstruts.poc.Test2</option> 
                            <!-- Here comes a lot of interface packages, public classes, etc as the last one -->    
<!--                    <option><![CDATA[
                        -keepclassmembers enum * {
                            public static **[] values();
                            public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
                        }                       
                        ]]></option>        -->
             <option>-injar ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</option>
                <option>-outjar ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-proguarded.${project.packaging}</option>
                </options>
                <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                <libs>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>                    
                </libs>
                <proguardVersion>4.8</proguardVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>          
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am new to proguard,
I have some configuration issue to obfuscate the class files with web application
can you please help me on it.
The Problem is the class files are not generates in proguarded war in /WEB-INF/classes/ it is having full package but does't have .class files
The below is actual war snap
[image: Acutal Jar]

and the following is the proguarded war
[image: Proguard generated war]

Please excuse my bad english.

Comment: Why is there no maven-war-plugin if your project is web-based?

Comment: I have maven war plugin  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
please check once

Comment: FYI, war file generated fine, the issue with the proguard obfuscation